# drupal 6.19 password reset redirect

Tags: php, drupal-6

I trying in drupal 6.19  to redirect the 'user/password' page after submit to 'alter location'   then user page.

I am using in theme hook to get the preprocess function and in it I edit the $variables as:

```
$variables['form']['#action'] = 'alter location';
```

and after that I use drupal_render() .

in the drupal debug I see that the #action is set to the 'alter location' but in the 
html tag I still see action='user/password' and it not redirect me to the desired location.

Thanks in advance

Comment: i'm not sure about it but see if you can change something like `$variables['form']['redirect'] = 'alter location';`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to this [comment](http://drupal.org/node/290462#comment-1035899)

```
    /**
* Implementation of hook_form_alter().
*/
function jm_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  if (isset($form['#node']) && $form['#node']->type .'_node_form' == $form_id) {
    $form['buttons']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'jm_redirect_handler';
  }
}

/**
* Attaches the redirect to the submitted form.
*
* @param unknown_type $form
* @param unknown_type $form_state
* @return unknown
*/
function jm_redirect_handler($form, &$form_state) {
  if ($form_state['nid']) {
    // reloading as I do not know the node type context. You probably do not need to :), just set the redirect using $form_state['nid']
    $node = node_load(array('nid' => $form_state['nid']));
    switch($node->type) {
      case 'project':
        $form_state['redirect'] = 'projects/'. $node->nid;
    }
  }
}
```

I found solution that works.

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal forms work like this: User requests a page containing the form. A function creates a structured array that makes up that form. This array gets rendered in the theme layer. If the user submits the form, Drupal calls the same routine to again build the structured array. But now it's used to validate and process user input. If the processing routine returns a path or `?destination` or `#redirect` is set, Drupal does an internal redirect. If not, the same form is displayed again. Then and only then is your code in the theming layer executed. However it's to late to inject `#redirect`. Drupal won't look at it anymore.

Changing the `#action` is rather senseless as thereby the user input is sent to a URL that Drupal's menu system translates and calls routines that do not expect nor process the input.

Try the [path redirect](http://drupal.org/project/path_redirect) module. If it does not work follow these [instructions to create a custom module](http://drupal.org/node/134000).

Answer (score 0):

thanks!!!

I solve it by useing -> hook_form_FORM_ID_alter function as like.... mymodulename_form_FORM_ID_alter

as saw here [link text](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/6)

this is what I did and it did the job for me:

function mymodulename_form_FORM_ID_alter (&$form){
  $form['#action'] = 'alter_location';
}